# angular material2 does not work in an Angular 2.0.0 app

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material2

I have an app that loads with Angular 2.0.0, the 9/14/16 release after all the rc releases. I am trying to add Angular Material2, the official MD release from the Google team.  I am copy/pasting code from their Getting Started site, except I am using Atom and not angular-cli, as I have already built the beginnings of the app. Atom-typescript finds everything and says there are no errors.  But despite thrashing with a lot of trials, I repeatedly get these not found Console errors when the modified app fails to load.

zone.js:1263 GET http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular2-material/button/ 404 (Not Found)scheduleTask @ zone.js:1263

home:27 Error: (SystemJS) XHR error (404 Not Found) loading http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular2-material/button(…)

zone.js:1263 GET http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular2-material/list/ 404 (Not Found)

I have looked at the node_modules files above and they exist in my code.

Per instructions in Getting Started, relevant code is:

app.module.ts

```
import { MdButtonModule } from '@angular2-material/button';
import { MdListModule } from '@angular2-material/list';
@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule,
                  FormsModule,
                  MdButtonModule,
                  MdListModule,
                  routing
  ],
```

systemjs.config.js

```
var map = {
'@angular2-material':                   'node_modules/@angular2-material',
'@angular2-material/core':                   'node_modules/@angular2-material/core/core',
'@angular2-material/list':                   'node_modules/@angular2-material/list',
'@angular2-material/button':                   'node_modules/@angular2-material/button'
};
var packages = {
'app':                        { main: 'main.js',  defaultExtension: 'js' },
'rxjs':                       { defaultExtension: 'js' },
'angular2-in-memory-web-api': { main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js' },
};
function packIndex(pkgName) {
packages['@angular/'+pkgName] = { main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js' };
}
function packUmd(pkgName) {
packages['@angular/'+pkgName] = { main: 'bundles/' + pkgName + '.umd.js', defaultExtension: 'js' };
}
var setPackageConfig = System.packageWithIndex ? packIndex : packUmd;
ngPackageNames.forEach(setPackageConfig);
```

The HTML page has a couple md-list, md-list-item and md-button tags.

What should I change?

Comment: https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/src/demo-app/system-config.ts

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39459721/angular2-angular2-material-error-xhr-error-404-not-found-loading-http-l/39462481#39462481

Comment: https://medium.com/codingthesmartway-com-blog/using-material-design-in-angular-2-83a3128c58b7#.q8t2re7z6

Comment: Can you show your package.json's dependednices and devDependencies?

Comment: @scarabaeus, the package.json is 75 lines. It includes several lines like "@angular2-material/button": "2.0.0-alpha.8-1"  Can you be specific?

Comment: @yurzui, I'll study the 3 links Friday. The 1st and 3d links use "barrels" and "bundles".  I think they are gone in Angular 2.0.0.  Are these links current with the 2.0.0 release?

Comment: Since the system.config.js file may be the problem area, I have added more, but not all of its content, to the above post.

Comment: Got this working today with ng 2.0.0 (final) and the material 2.0.0-alpha.8-2 modules.  I used the third link that @yurzui provided.  My system.js.config looks quite a bit different than yours. Too much to post here, but one of the things I had to add was in the maps variable:  '@angular2-material/core': 'npm:@angular2-material/core/core.umd.js',
      '@angular2-material/button': 'npm:@angular2-material/button/button.umd.js',

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to get it working this morning as of (9/16) with Angular2 (final),  Angular2-Material 2.0.0-alpha.8-2, and TypeScript 2.0.0.  As you can see in the package.json below, I have a majority of the currently available Angular2 Material components installed (and running) by following the instructions from [this video](https://medium.com/codingthesmartway-com-blog/using-material-design-in-angular-2-83a3128c58b7#.wkert55vw).

Posting my system.config.ts so you can see it in hopes that it will help you troubleshoot.

```
/**
 * System configuration for Angular 2 samples
 * Adjust as necessary for your application needs.
 */
(function (global) {
  System.config({
    paths: {
      // paths serve as alias
      'npm:': 'node_modules/'
    },
    // map tells the System loader where to look for things
    map: {
      // our app is within the app folder
      app: 'app',
      // angular bundles
      '@angular/core': 'npm:@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js',
      '@angular/common': 'npm:@angular/common/bundles/common.umd.js',
      '@angular/compiler': 'npm:@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js',
      '@angular/platform-browser': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser.umd.js',
      '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js',
      '@angular/http': 'npm:@angular/http/bundles/http.umd.js',
      '@angular/router': 'npm:@angular/router/bundles/router.umd.js',
      '@angular/forms': 'npm:@angular/forms/bundles/forms.umd.js',

      // other libraries
      'rxjs':                       'npm:rxjs',
      'angular2-in-memory-web-api': 'npm:angular2-in-memory-web-api',

      // Angular2-Material
      '@angular2-material/core': 'npm:@angular2-material/core/core.umd.js',
      '@angular2-material/button': 'npm:@angular2-material/button/button.umd.js',
      '@angular2-material/card': 'npm:@angular2-material/card/card.umd.js',
      '@angular2-material/checkbox': 'npm:@angular2-material/checkbox/checkbox.umd.js',
      '@angular2-material/grid-list': 'npm:@angular2-material/grid-list/grid-list.umd.js',
      '@angular2-material/icon': 'npm:@angular2-material/icon/icon.umd.js',
      '@angular2-material/input': 'npm:@angular2-material/input/input.umd.js',
      '@angular2-material/list': 'npm:@angular2-material/list/list.umd.js',
      '@angular2-material/radio': 'npm:@angular2-material/radio/radio.umd.js',
      '@angular2-material/sidenav': 'npm:@angular2-material/sidenav/sidenav.umd.js',
      '@angular2-material/toolbar': 'npm:@angular2-material/toolbar/toolbar.umd.js',
    },
    // packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
    packages: {
      app: {
        main: './main.js',
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      },
      rxjs: {
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      },
      'angular2-in-memory-web-api': {
        main: './index.js',
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      }
    }
  });
})(this);
```

Relevant portion of my package.json:

```
      ...   
      "dependencies": {
        "@angular/common": "~2.0.0",
        "@angular/compiler": "~2.0.0",
        "@angular/core": "~2.0.0",
        "@angular/forms": "~2.0.0",
        "@angular/http": "~2.0.0",
        "@angular/platform-browser": "~2.0.0",
        "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~2.0.0",
        "@angular/router": "~3.0.0",
        "@angular/upgrade": "~2.0.0",
        "@angular2-material/button": "^2.0.0-alpha.8-2",
        "@angular2-material/card": "^2.0.0-alpha.8-2",
        "@angular2-material/checkbox": "^2.0.0-alpha.8-2",
        "@angular2-material/core": "^2.0.0-alpha.8-2",
        "@angular2-material/grid-list": "^2.0.0-alpha.8-2",
        "@angular2-material/icon": "^2.0.0-alpha.8-2",
        "@angular2-material/input": "^2.0.0-alpha.8-2",
        "@angular2-material/list": "^2.0.0-alpha.8-2",
        "@angular2-material/radio": "^2.0.0-alpha.8-2",
        "@angular2-material/sidenav": "^2.0.0-alpha.8-2",
        "@angular2-material/toolbar": "^2.0.0-alpha.8-2",
        "angular2-in-memory-web-api": "~0.0.19",
        "core-js": "^2.4.1",
        "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
        "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.3",
        "rxjs": "~5.0.0-beta.12",
        "systemjs": "~0.19.27",
        "zone.js": "^0.6.21"
      },
      "devDependencies": {
        "concurrently": "^2.2.0",
        "lite-server": "^2.2.2",
        "typescript": "^2.0.0",
        "typings": "^1.3.2"
      }
      ...
```

Updated typescript to version 2.0.0.

Also had to register typings for hammerjs (Touch gesture support), but I believe you'll only need this if you're using `MdIconModule`.

Comment: Yes, the system.config file was helpful and the video link was essential to clean up the next round of errors. But it now loads. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

With breaking changes on Angular Material 2 release 2.0.0-alpha.9, you can simply map this one line in systemjs.config.ts

```
'@angular/material': 'npm:@angular/material/material.umd.js',
```

The package.json also becomes simpler with:

```
"@angular/material": "^2.0.0-alpha.9-3"
```

And don't forget to import the NgModule

```
import { MaterialModule } from '@angular/material';
@NgModule({
  ...
  imports: [MaterialModule.forRoot()],
  ...
})
```

From [material2 release](https://github.com/angular/material2/releases):

> Angular Material has changed from @angular2-material/... packages to a
>   single package under @angular/material. Along with this change, there
>   is a new NgModule, MaterialModule, that contains all of the
>   components. ...